# Different layout for nexus 4 and galaxy nexus

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very confused. I need to design different layouts for nexus 4(768x1280) and galaxy nexus(720x1280). But both fall into xhdpi. So dimen-xhdpi covers both of these categories. What new dimen.xml files should I make to cover these sizes individually? A similar question suggested using dimens-sw-360dp for galaxy nexus which did not work for me as galxy nexus layout was still affected by dimens-xhdpi.

Comment: "I need to design different layouts for nexus 4(768x1280) and galaxy nexus(720x1280)" -- why? "So dimen-xhdpi covers both of these categories" -- density (pixels per inch) and resolution (pixels) are not the same thing.

Comment: I am just asking what dimen files should I make to design these layouts independently